# select statement where condition returns multiple rows

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I am trying to get all the results from multiple rows returned by the same where condition:

```
public static String getResult(String mycondition)
   {    
      ResultSet rsData = sql.RunSelect("select col1 from my_table where con ='"+myCondition+"'");
      if (rsData.next())
      {
         String result = rsData,getString("col1");
      }
   }
```

Note that there is an id column that makes these rows distinguishable.
The display in jsp page should make text fields for every row returned.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a `List<String>` or use a char to separate the multiple strings in a single `String`. IMO it would be better returning a `List<String>`:

```
public static List<String> getResult(String mycondition) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultSet rsData = sql.RunSelect("select col1 from my_table where con='"
        +myCondition+"'");
    while (rsData.next()) {
        results.add(rsData.getString("col1"));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Also, this method is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Note that your parameters should be sent apart from the query. Probably you can improve your `sql.RunSelect` method to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`. This is a basic example of the code skeleton:

```
public ResultSet runSelect(String query, Object ... params) {
    //assumes you already have your Connection
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    int i = 1;
    for(Object param : params) {
        pstmt.setObject(i++, param);
    }
    return pstmt.executeQuery();
}
```

So now you could modify your method to

```
public static List<String> getResult(String mycondition) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    //using the new runSelect method
    ResultSet rsData = sql.runSelect(
        "select col1 from my_table where con=?", mycondition);
    while (rsData.next()) {
        results.add(rsData.getString("col1"));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: @jlordo I know the joke (and re read it when I'm bored) sorry, just updated the answer. By the way, I just respected current OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use while loop instead of if loop

instead of - if (rsData.next())

use -  while (rsData.next())

Although answer of @Luiggi Mendoza is best if you want security in your code